# Unable to build initWithStyle method...

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I have an iPad app, built in XCode4.5, using Storyboards and iOS6.  I have a UITableView that I am trying to fill from a CoreData store using MagicalRecord.  This is the piece of my code that's giving me problems:

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier  {

    self = [super initWithStyle:<#style#> reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];  //  <--

    if(self) {
        //  initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm getting a build error (on the line with the //  <--) saying "expected expression".  I have looked in SO, Google and absolutely can not figure this out! (I have the same code running in another app with no problems).

Can someone please tell me how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know if that was a paste mistake or whatever, buu should write it this way:

```
self = [super initWithStyle: style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Comment: I think I didn't hit the tab key when it had the little blue button around "style"... works fine now... thank you so much1